# python scrapy css selector not constant format scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning Python scrapy, and i have a trouble gathering information on not constant html formats.

for example, on the website i am trying to scrape,
some are in below format:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

while some may be in below format:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

some are wrapped around 'p' tags but some are not. how can i scrape whether texts are wrapped in 'p' tag or not? is there a condition checker?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this.  The result is list which you could process after that.
With /text - it will search text only in the current element.
With //text - also on the child node (nodes)

```
html1 = """
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
"""
sel = scrapy.Selector( text = html1 )
print(sel.xpath('//div[@class="two"]//text()').extract())


html2 = """
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
"""
sel = scrapy.Selector( text = html2 )
print(sel.xpath('//div[@class="two"]//text()').extract())
```

Output:

```
['\n    ', 'hello', '\n  ']
['\n    hello\n  ']
```